# How to delete an entire row if two cells contain specific text

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA code which can delete an entire row, if two cells (which can be in any column of the sheet) contains a specific text.

I have a daily generated print reporting file and in this file exists the text (in a non specific column) `"printed BlackWhitepages, total = #"` and `"printed Colourpages, total = #"` also in any column.

The # stands for a number, so in my file there could be 0-99999...., depending on how many pages were printed.

The file has columns from `A` to `BA` and thousands of rows, and the `Blackwhitepages` and `Colourpages` text could be on each column, depending on the print job.

I want the VBA to look at the entire sheet, and if a row contains **`"printed BlackWhitepages, total = 0"`** and **`"printed Colourpages, total = 0"`**, the entire row should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Code:

```
Sub DeleteRow()

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    VarBnW = 0
    VarCol = 0
    For Each cell In Range("A" & i & ":" & "BA" & i)

        If Trim(cell.Value) = "Gedruckte Schwarzweißseiten, insgesamt = 0" Then VarBnW = 1
        If Trim(cell.Value) = "Gedruckte Farbseiten, insgesamt = 0" Then VarCol = 1

        If VarCol + VarBnW = 2 Then
            MsgBox cell.Address
            cell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If

    Next cell
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello izzymo, thanks for the code, but if i activate it nothing happens. I created a testfile for you, that you can see how my data looks like. You can download it here [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14554224/testfile.zip). I only deleted one coloum which has included the printed filenames (to ensure the privacy) and i marked the cells yellow which should be deleted, see row 17,45,46,47,119,193,194 and 197.

Comment: Just for information, the text in the file is in german, so the text which has to be deleted is **"Gedruckte Schwarzweißseiten, insgesamt = 0"** and **" Gedruckte Farbseiten, insgesamt = 0"**

Comment: The reason it wasn't working was because of a space at the beginning of the text. I have edited the code now to account for that. and also amended the code to German. Please refer to the edited answer above.

Comment: thanks for the edited code, its working perfect :), so my question is answered. sorry that i answer here and not above, but i dont know exactly where i should post my comment, that your code helped me.